# Change label text on button press

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton, uitextfield

I have thirty-one labels, and these labels show the days of the month; I want to push a button and change all the labels to display the days of the next month. Example: if I have the days of July showing, and I want change to August, I press a button and all my labels change values. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible. What exactly is your question? What have you tried? What worked and what didn't?

Comment: I want to know how can I make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You probably should have a look at [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) and [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You could use NSDateComponents like this:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setYear:2011];
[components setDay:1];
[components setMonth:month];
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

and you increment the month variable each time you press a button.
Good thing with NSDateComponents is that the components are wrapped, so if you set month to 24 you'll get a date 2 years in the future.

Comment: and How can I link my label with component?

Comment: use a [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to format the date and set the [text property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW6) of the UILabel with the result from `[dateFormatter stringFromDate:...]`